# TypeORM- Use the joined entity instead?

Tags: typeorm, nestjs

I've got an `auth_token` table and `user` table. I'd like to resolve a user from a given auth token using the query builder. The issue I'm having is that after joining, the return type still thinks it's going to be an `AuthToken`. Is there a way to tell the query builder to use the joined entity instead?

```
return await this.authTokenRepository
  .createQueryBuilder()
  .where({
    token: token
  })
  .innerJoinAndSelect(User, 'user')
  .getOne();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to return an entity of type user I recommend to use the User repository:

```
return await this.userTokenRepository
  .createQueryBuilder('user')
  .leftJoinAndSelect('user.token', 'token')
  .where({
    token: token
  })
  .getOne();
```